# How to read the commentary of a certain svn commit version using terminal?

Tags: linux, svn, terminal

How to read the commentary of a certain commit version using terminal? Like:
svn commit_version read or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

It's simple:

```
svn log -c<svn revision> <svn url>
```

Example Output:

```
svn log -c 51529 svn+ssh://localhost/svn/project
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r51529 | bubba | 2010-06-29 16:48:49 +0100 (Tue, 29 Jun 2010) | 1 line

checking in for safety reasons
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

To read `svn` commit messages you use the command `svn log` plus optional parameters.

To get the commit log of a specific revision (r14 for example) you usually run

```
svn log -r 14
```

A more detailed description of the `svn log` command is available in the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/de/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html)

You might also want to run the output through a pager

```
svn log | less
```